# Famous, drag over surface

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, drag, famous-engine, famous-framework

Is there a way in Famous, how to contact surface that another was dragged over him but event is still active and no ended ? Something like  mouseover but for touch events.

Comment: Is this really specific to Famous?  Can you bind to the `'touchmove'` event?  If this is for drag & drop, you could ignore the `'touchmove'` event unless a drag is in progress... something like `...on('touchmove', function() { if (!hasDragItem) return; else ... })`, where `hasDragItem` is a variable you defined elsewhere (when the drag started).

Comment: Thanks for response. I can bind to 'touchmove' event, but this event doesn't return anything offsetX/offsetY in return value. By specification it should be returned. Firstly I used that value for computing center of clicked element and than to compute if touchmove is inersecting other element because I could compute position of other element. I don't know starting position of element but I can compute positions of other elements depending on clicked/touched element. Here is example [http://imgur.com/xjjKCgs](http://imgur.com/xjjKCgs) it is similar to dots game